# Disappearing left quotation mark in `\texttt{}` when using babel (norwegian)

Tags: babel, punctuation, typewriter

When using the package `babel` with the norwegian option (`\usepackage[norsk]{babel}`), double-quotation marks (`"`) in `\texttt{}` disappear if they occur before certain letters (e.g., `b`, `d`, and `f`), but not for others. Is there any solution to this?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\begin{document}
\texttt{"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"} 

\texttt{"a"} \texttt{"b"} \texttt{"c"} \texttt{"d"} \texttt{"e"} \texttt{"f"}
\end{document}
```

**with `\usepackage[norsk]{babel}`** (leading `"` removed sometimes)

[image]

**without `\usepackage[norsk]{babel}`** (this is how I want it to be)

[image]

Comment: As in Danish `"` is an active character in Norsk, if we look in `norsk.ldf` we see for example that `\declare@shorthand{norsk}{"e}{\textormath{\bbl@disc e{\'e}}{}}`, honestly I have no idea what it is doing here, but there is your rexplanation

Comment: Ahh it is explained further in `norsk.pdf` you should hjave it on your computer, else find it on http://texdoc.net

Comment: What are you trying to typeset? If you want to show code better use \verb or some other verbatim command.

Comment: this is being generated from a [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/)-markdown file, so I can't change the environment.

Comment: thanks @daleif, this looks interesting... maybe the solution is to make an own `.ldf` file? My problem is that I still want norwegian chapter/section/title names etc but not the `"` behaviour...

Comment: Instead of using `\texttt` all the time, use a custom macro, that will not have `"` being an active char.

Comment: As I said, I can't change that short of redefining `\texttt{}` since the tex-code is generated automatically...

Comment: If you don't need the " shorthand, disable it with `\shorthandoff{"}`. You can also use `\usepackage[norsk,shorthands=off]{babel}`

Comment: perfect, thank you so much - exactly what I need! Want to put this in an answer so that it can be accepted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable shorthands completly

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[norsk,shorthands=off]{babel}
\begin{document}
\texttt{"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"} 

\texttt{"a"} \texttt{"b"} \texttt{"c"} \texttt{"d"} \texttt{"e"} \texttt{"f"}
\end{document}
```

or locally

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\begin{document}
\texttt{"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"} 

\shorthandsoff{"} 
\texttt{"a"} \texttt{"b"} \texttt{"c"} \texttt{"d"} \texttt{"e"} \texttt{"f"}
\end{document}
```